# pass table row values to controller using jquery selector and ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, jquery-selectors

I'm trying to pass a row values by a click on its button using jquery selection and Ajax to pass it to controller. After alot of tries, It finally gets the values of the single row right but it just stops before the Ajax and i can't figure out why.
here is my view

```
@model ExitApplication.MyModel.TheUserListViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Edit user data";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Edit user data</h2>
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()

<table id="tableId">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.Label("User ID")
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.Label("Account")
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.Label("Lob")
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.Label("Group")
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.Label("Start Date")
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.Label("Training start Date")
            </th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>

    </thead>
    @for (int i = 0; i < Model.theUserTables.Count; i++)
    {
        <tbody>

            <tr data-id="@Model.theUserTables[i].Group">
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => modelItem.theUserTables[i].UserID)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => modelItem.theUserTables[i].Account)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => modelItem.theUserTables[i].Lob)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => modelItem.theUserTables[i].Group)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => modelItem.theUserTables[i].StartDate)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => modelItem.theUserTables[i].TrainingDate)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => modelItem.theUserTables[i].PersonID)
                </td>
                <td>
                    <a href="javascript:;" class="EditID" data-id="@Model.theUserTables[i].Group">Update User Data</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    }

</table>
```

and here is the script:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $('#tableId').DataTable({
                dom: 'Bfrtip',
                "buttons": [
                    'copy',
                    'excel'],
            });
        });

        $(document).ready(function () {
            var token = $("[name='__RequestVerificationToken']").val();
            var headers = {};
            headers['__RequestVerificationToken'] = token;
            $('table tr').click(function () {
                var $tds = $(this).find('td'),
                    UserID = $tds.eq(0).text(),
                    Account = $tds.eq(1).text(),
                    Lob = $tds.eq(2).text(),
                    Group = $tds.eq(3).text(),
                    StartDate = $tds.eq(4).text(),
                    TrainingDate = $tds.eq(5).text()
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: '/Temp/EditUserData',
                    headers: headers,
                    data: { UserID, Account, Lob, Group, StartDate, TrainingDate},
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (r) {
                        window.location.href = "IndexTranNewRequest";
                    }
                })
            });
        });
```

the method in controller:

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult EditUserData(string UserID, string Account, string Lob, string Group, string StartDate, string TrainingDate)
        { }
```

Thank you in advance for your time.

Comment: Seeing any error inside browser console ? Also ,why you have `window.location.href = "IndexTranNewRequest";` ?

Comment: no errors at all. it gets the data right and passes it to the data in the ajax but it never does its job by passing the data to the method in the controller. for ```window.location.href = "IndexTranNewRequest";``` i just wants after the saving to database, it redirects to the page "IndexTranNewRequest"

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in the success. when i hashed it, it worked and passed the data to the controller. I don't know why but it's supposed to be the redirection happens from the ajax.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            var token = $("[name='__RequestVerificationToken']").val();
            var headers = {};
            headers['__RequestVerificationToken'] = token;
            $('table tr').click(function () {
                var $tds = $(this).find('td'),
                    UserID = $tds.eq(0).text(),
                    Account = $tds.eq(1).text(),
                    Lob = $tds.eq(2).text(),
                    Group = $tds.eq(3).text(),
                    StartDate = $tds.eq(4).text(),
                    TrainingDate = $tds.eq(5).text()
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: '/Temp/EditUserData',
                    headers: headers,
                    data: { UserID, Account, Lob, Group, StartDate, TrainingDate},
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    
                })
            });
        });
```